# Issue with an icon on Android's PopupWindow

Tags: android, popupwindow

I have an app in which I'm opening a PopupWindow, with a couple of images, a text box and an icon of a trash bin below the tex box.

The problem is when I'm presenting the PopupWindow, sometimes when I'm opening the window the icon seems small, and on other times (most of the times) the icon seems as I defined it.

```
popUpView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_packpresent, (ViewGroup)ma.findViewById(R.layout.activity_main));

pw = new PopupWindow(
        popUpView,
        ma.f.getView().getMeasuredWidth(), //400
        ma.f.getView().getMeasuredHeight(), //800
        true);
pw.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDismiss() {
        System.out.println("Dismissed!!");

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //MainActivity.packButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                try {
                    image.recycle();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                ma.handlePopUpDissmiss();
            }
        });
    }
});

trash = (ImageButton)popUpView.findViewById(R.id.trashBin);
trash.getLayoutParams().height = (int)((MainActivity.wantedPicSize)*(3.0/4.0));
trash.getLayoutParams().width = (int)((MainActivity.wantedPicSize)*(3.0/4.0));

pw.showAtLocation(map, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
pw.update();
```

The layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/lID">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rID"
        android:background="@drawable/back5">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="125px"
            android:layout_height="200px"
            android:id="@+id/mImageView"
            android:background="@drawable/com_facebook_picker_default_separator_color"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_below="@+id/mImageView"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:editable="false"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageViewR"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageViewR"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageViewL"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageViewL" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="125px"
            android:layout_height="200px"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewRR"
            android:background="@drawable/com_facebook_picker_default_separator_color"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageViewR"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="125px"
            android:layout_height="200px"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewLL"
            android:background="@drawable/com_facebook_picker_default_separator_color"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageViewL"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="125px"
            android:layout_height="200px"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewR"
            android:background="@drawable/com_facebook_picker_default_separator_color"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/mImageView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mImageView" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="125px"
            android:layout_height="200px"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewL"
            android:background="@drawable/com_facebook_picker_default_separator_color"
            android:layout_above="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/mImageView" />

        <GridView
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:id="@+id/gridView"
            android:layout_above="@+id/mImageView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageViewRR"
            android:background="@drawable/line"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageViewLL"
            android:layout_below="@+id/gridView" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageViewRR"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/trashBin"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/trash_bin" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is there any warning regarding to the popup in the logcat?

Comment: Why you are playing with height and width so much, any specific reason?

Comment: what do you mean by saying `playing with height and width so much`? I want the size to be as written in my question. Is that wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use a .9 patch image which can be generated here: [.9 patch generator](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html)

Or you can use any of these icon generators here and see if that works: [Android Asset Studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html)

Both links are very useful.